# OpenGL draw lines based on Lat/Lon Coordinates

Tags: c#, opengl

I need some help with drawing lines from lat/lon coordinates to an OpenGL canvas.

```
Gl.glViewport(0, 0, simpleOpenGlControl.ClientRectangle.Width, simpleOpenGlControl.ClientRectangle.Height);
Gl.glMatrixMode(Gl.GL_PROJECTION);
Gl.glLoadIdentity();
Gl.glOrtho(0, simpleOpenGlControl.ClientRectangle.Width, 0, simpleOpenGlControl.ClientRectangle.Height, -1, 1);

Gl.glMatrixMode(Gl.GL_MODELVIEW);
Gl.glLoadIdentity();

Gl.glClear(Gl.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
Gl.glBegin(Gl.GL_LINES);
Gl.glVertex2d(getX(36.0740197, -115.1051997), getY(36.0740197, -115.1051997));
Gl.glVertex2d(getX(36.0740197, -115.0845997), getY(36.0740197, -115.0845997));
Gl.glEnd();

Gl.glFlush();
```

And here's the methods to convert the lat/lon to XY:

```
public static double ToRadians(double valueInDegrees)
{
    return (Math.PI / 180) * valueInDegrees;
}

public double getY(double lat, double lon)
{
    double mercN = Math.Log(Math.Tan((Math.PI / 4) + (ToRadians(lat) / 2)));
    return (simpleOpenGlControl.ClientRectangle.Height / 2) - (simpleOpenGlControl.ClientRectangle.Width * mercN / (2 * Math.PI));
}

public double getX(double lat, double lon)
{
    return (lon + 180) * (simpleOpenGlControl.ClientRectangle.Width / 360);
}
```

However, when I run the application, nothing is drawn on the canvas. Any ideas? Additionally, the Lat/Lon coordinates are in pairs:

```
StartLon="-118.1624997" StartLat="33.9512797" EndLon="-118.1664997" EndLat="33.9508597"
```

With the conversion code, I these XY coordinates for `36.0740197, -115.1051997`

```
129.7896006
181.797964976478
```

If someone can point me in the right direction, I'd much appreciate it!

Comment: Firstly, are you sure the `OpenGL` control has been successfully initialized? Are you doing it yourself?  Secondly, why not specify the desired coordinate system in the `glOrtho` instead of making calculations yourself?  And the last, do you use the double-buffering and the `Gdi.SwapBuffers`?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How exactly do I define a coordinate system with `glOrtho`? Does this mean I can plug-in lat/loncoordinates into this and it will draw them?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to replicate your code and successfully draw lines between given points.
(Your lat/lon coordinate values of two points are too close to be noticeable but I was able to see a spec of line between them.)

Based on this, I wonder where you have put your first code listing (the part you setup viewport and draw lines) in your main program.

Try to render something simpler and see whether your OpenGL context is working correctly.